# When do we use dot product and when do we use cross product?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, torque, geometry

I actually dont understand that when do we use cross product and when to use dot product ……it is very difficult to remember that a torque is cross product and work done is dot product. please tell me the reasons behind these so that i can understand the concept not just blindly memorize?

Comment: Torque is a vector (an axial vector if we're pedantic), while work is a scalar. Do you wish to ask why that is so, or do you understand it? Because that's enough information to work out which product to use.

Comment: Yeah please explain more to me….

Comment: A torque cannot be completely defined without giving it a sense of rotation i.e. clockwise vs anticlockwise. So torque couldn't be defined using a dot product since that gives a scalar output.

Comment: Why is work a scalar: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/418187/why-is-work-scalar-and-the-dot-product-of-force-and-displacement?rq=1

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/516069/392

Comment: Does https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/518467/392 answer your question, as far as the cross products at least?

Comment: The simplest intuition is given by https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/37884/392

Answer (score 0):

The cross product's output is a vector and it tells you how much of the two vectors are at right angles to each other. The cross product of parallel vectors is zero. The cross product of two perpendicular vectors is another vector in the direction perpendicular to both of them with the magnitude of both vectors multiplied.

The dot product's output is a number (scalar) and it tells you how much the two vectors are in parallel to each other. The dot product of two parallel vectors is the product of their lengths. The dot product of two vectors at right angles to each other is zero.